# Jquery/Ajax error when returning json of php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

In my PHP I am collecting data from a table and echoing it with the JSON format.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
 include "bddata.php";
 header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM categoria ORDER BY idcategoria ASC ";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $json[]=$row;
}

$data["data"]=$json;
//test variables to get in ajax
$data["idcategoria"] = $data["data"][0]["idcategoria"];
$data["nome_categoria"] = $data["data"][0]["nome_categoria"];
//echo $data["nome_categoria"];

//var_dump($data["data"][1]);

print json_encode($data);

$conn->close();
?>
```

This code returns something like:

```
idcategoria "21"

nome_categoria "Hotel"

1
idcategoria "22"

nome_categoria "Mecanica"

//my test variables

idcategoria "21"

nome_categoria "Hotel"
```

**JS:**

```
function inicializarForm(data) {
  var id;
  var nome;
  id = val(data["idcategoria"]);
  nome = val(data["nome_categoria"]);
  //$("#id").val(data["idcategoria"]);
  //$("#nome").val(data["nome_categoria"]);
}


$.ajax({
  url: "../php/busca.categoria2.php",
  type: "ajax",
  dataType: "json"

}).done(function(data) {
  window.alert("entrei na funcao");
  console.log(data)
  inicializarForm(data)
  console.log(nome);
  return;

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  console.error(textStatus);
  window.alert("Erro, tente novamente!");
  console.log(textStatus);

}).always(function() {

});
```

In my browser console, I get an error.

Could someone give me an idea of what might be happening?

Initial purpose: to log the `idcategory` value and `category_name` in the console.

Real purpose: get the PHP JSON and set up an interactive menu coming with the categories registered in the database.

Comment: What is `type: "ajax"`? ... Try: `type: "GET"` instead.

Comment: still remains the error, just goes through the .fail function

Comment: It would be useful if you told us what error you were getting. One possibility, when you call `$data["data"][0]["idcategoria"]`, you would get an index error if the sql query returns no rows.

Comment: Michael Beeson, when I query with this format $ data ["date"] [0] ["idcategory"] it normally returns me the data written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code version.

**PHP**

```
<?php
include "bddata.php";
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM categoria ORDER BY idcategoria ASC ";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $json[]=$row;
}

/*
$json = array(
    0 => array(
        'idcategoria' => 1,
        'nome_categoria' => 'Category 1'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'idcategoria' => 2,
        'nome_categoria' => 'Category 2'
    ),
);
*/

$data["data"]=$json;

print json_encode($data);

$conn->close();
```

**HTML & JS**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Show data</title>
    <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
</ul>
<script>
function inicializarForm(data) {
    $.map(data, function(i) {
        $("#menu").append("<li><a href='#categoria_"+ i.idcategoria +"'>"+ i.nome_categoria +"</a></li>");
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: "categoria2.php",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data) {
    window.alert("entrei na funcao");
    console.log(data['data']);
    inicializarForm(data['data']);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.error(textStatus);
    window.alert("Erro, tente novamente!");
    console.log(textStatus);
}).always(function() {

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use `$.map()` or `$.each()` jquery function to loop data returned from JSON that has been converted to javascript array.

Comment: friend had already written a code equal to yours and discovered the problem, was pulling the directory relative to js to php, but actually when you assign js to index, the path should be relative to it. Thank you so much for the light !! I am extremely grateful! Thank you very much !